# How can I retrieve the cursor position in an ExtJS text area field?

Tags: extjs, cursor

I defined a text area field in an extJS window as follows:

```
       me.myTextArea = Ext.create({
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        editable: true,
        selectOnFocus: false,
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function() {
                this.focus(true);
                let cursorPos = this.getValue().length;
                this.selectText(cursorPos, cursorPos);
            }
        }
    });
```

I added the text area field to a panel contained within a window, and I set the text area field as focus element. I prevented the text there to be selected after the textarea field's being rendered. I would like to add the following feature. On closing the window, I will be able to get the position the cursor has within the text area field. So far, my attemps at resolving the problem were withou success. I set up an alert as follows:

```
    listeners: {
    'close': function(me) {
        alert(me.getCaretPos(cmp.myTextArea.getEl().getId()));
    }
},
```

Now the function named "getCaretPos" is designed to get the cursor position. I did not invent the function, but I found in on the net. Haplessly, the function does not work, it always returns -1:

```
    getCaretPos: function(id){
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var rng, ii=-1;
    if(typeof el.selectionStart=="number") {
        ii=el.selectionStart;
    } else if (document.selection && el.createTextRange){
        rng=document.selection.createRange();
        rng.collapse(true);
        rng.moveStart("character", -el.value.length);
        ii=rng.text.length;
    }
    return ii;
}
```

Especially, I do not undertsand, why "el.selectionStart" is always undefined in the function. I would be very glad if somebody could help me in resolving this mystery.

Answer (score 0):

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2e4l)**, I have created a `custometextarea` using `extend:Ext.form.field.TextArea` and putted some custom method. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirements.

I have checked this code is working in ExtJS 4.x and later.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.define('CustomeTextArea', {
            extend: 'Ext.form.field.TextArea',
            xtype: 'customtextarea',

            inputTypeSelectionSupported: /text|password|search|tel|url/i,

            selectDir: {
                b: 'backward',
                back: 'backward',
                f: 'forward'
            },

            /*
             * this event will call get the cursoe postion inside of field
             * @return {NUMBER}
             */
            getCaretPos: function () {
                var dom = this.inputEl.dom,
                    pos, selection;

                if (this.inputTypeSelectionSupported.test(dom.type)) {
                    pos = dom.selectionStart;
                    selection = (typeof pos !== 'number') && this.getTextSelection();
                    if (selection) {
                        pos = selection[0];
                    }
                } else {
                    Ext.raise('Input type of "' + dom.type + '" does not support selectionStart');
                }

                return pos;
            },

            /*
             * this event will call selectText event
             * @params {NUMBER} pos
             */
            setCaretPos: function (pos) {
                this.selectText(pos, pos);
            },

            /*
             * @params {NUMBER} start
             * @params {NUMBER} end
             * @params {STRING} direction to select it is optional
             */
            selectText: function (start, end, direction) {
                var me = this,
                    range,
                    dom = me.inputEl.dom,
                    len;

                if (dom && me.inputTypeSelectionSupported.test(dom.type)) {
                    start = start || 0;
                    len = dom.value.length;
                    if (end === undefined) {
                        end = len;
                    }
                    direction = me.selectDir[direction] || direction || 'forward';
                    if (dom.setSelectionRange) {
                        dom.setSelectionRange(start, end, direction);
                    } else if (dom.createTextRange) {
                        range = dom.createTextRange();
                        range.moveStart('character', start);
                        range.moveEnd('character', -(len - end));
                        range.select();
                    }
                } else if (!me.inputTypeSelectionSupported.test(dom.type)) {
                    Ext.raise('Input type of "' + dom.type + '" does not support setSelectionRange');
                }

                return me;
            },

            //This event will select the text inside of textfield/textarea
            getTextSelection: function () {
                var dom = this.inputEl.dom;
                if (this.inputTypeSelectionSupported.test(dom.type)) {
                    return [
                        dom.selectionStart,
                        dom.selectionEnd,
                        dom.selectionDirection
                    ];
                } else {

                    Ext.raise('Input type of "' + this.dom.type + '" does not support selectionStart, selectionEnd and selectionDirection');

                    return [];
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'cursor position',
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'customtextarea',
                margin: 5,
                grow: true,
                name: 'message',
                fieldLabel: 'Message',
                labelAlign: 'top',
                value: 'How can I retrieve the cursor position in an ExtJS text area field?',
                anchor: '100%',
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: function (cmp) {
                        Ext.defer(function () {
                            cmp.focus(false); //if you pass true then it will automatically select text inside of field
                            let cursorPos = cmp.getValue().length;
                            cmp.selectText(0, cursorPos - 5, 'b');
                        }, 50)
                    }
                }
            }],
            listeners: {
                beforeclose: function (win) {
                    var textArea = win.down('customtextarea'),
                        pos = textArea.getCaretPos();

                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', `This is your cursor postion <b>${pos}</b>`)
                }
            }
        }).show();
    }
});
```